# Logout is not working in Laravel 5.3.10

Tags: php, authentication, logout, laravel-5.3, auth0

I am using Laravel 5.3.10. I am trying to use [auth0](https://auth0.com/). My route for logout in *web.php* is

`Route::get('/logout', function() {
    Auth::logout();
});`

But the logout is not working. It is giving me below error.

[image]

> ApiException in Authentication.php line 47: client_id was not set.

Could anyone help me in this regard ??

Comment: Have you followed the instructions provided in this link [instruction](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/laravel)?

Comment: Yes, I followed. I used 
`Route::get('/logout', function() {
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::home();
});` to logout. But it is giving me the above error. Thanks

Comment: Have you set this correctly? <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.2/lock.min.js"></script>
`<script type="text/javascript">
  var lock = new Auth0Lock('YOUR_CLIENT_ID', 'YOUR_NAMESPACE', {
    auth: {
      redirectUrl: '',
      responseType: 'code',
      params: {
        scope: 'openid email' // Learn about scopes: https://auth0.com/docs/scopes
      }
    }
  });
</script>`

Comment: Have you SET your own personal auth0 client ID & Namespace? new Auth0Lock('YOUR_CLIENT_ID', 'YOUR_NAMESPACE' .

Comment: Yes, I set all these.

Comment: It is complaining about your CLIENT_ID not been set, do you have client_id in your .env file?